# Mathematics - geometric progression question

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms

If $a$, $b$ and $c$ are in geometric progression, then what are $\log_ax$, $\log_bx$ and $\log_cx$ in?

What I did:
I substituted values for $x, a, b$ and $c$ and tried to solve it further.

What I got:
Using the value of x as 2 and a = 2 b = 4 c = 8:
I obtained that it is in harmonic progression.
$$\log_22, \log_42, \log_82$$
$$1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}$$

However, if I used x = 64, then I am not getting a harmonic progression. Instead, I got:
$$\log_264, \log_464, \log_864$$
$$6, 3, 2$$
I don't think that these numbers are in harmonic progression. What did I do wrong?

Btw. I know the answer is harmonic progression

Comment: $1/6$, $1/3$, $1/2$ is an arithmetic progression, so $6$, $3$, $2$ is a harmonic progression.

Comment: How though? What is the common difference between them? @JimmyK4542

Comment: @Cookies $1/3-1/6=1/6$, and $1/2-1/3=1/6$, so the common difference is $1/6$.

Comment: Oh.... I missed that. LOL

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$\log_y(x)=\frac{\log(x)}{\log(y)}$$
Now try examining 
$$\frac{1}{\log_b(x)}-\frac{1}{\log_a(x)}$$ and $$\frac{1}{\log_c(x)}-\frac{1}{\log_b(x)}$$

Keep in mind that $\log(u)-\log(v)=\log(\frac{u}{v})$.